# D3 Network Graph

Tags: json, d3.js

I'm very new to D3 and am trying to make a Network Graph

I have a .json file with two arrays like, one with the nodes, there name and a location, and the second has which node connects to which, this is a small example:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "site09","x": 317.5,"y": 282.5},
    {"id": "site01","x": 112,"y": 47}
],
"links": [
    {"node01": "site05", "node02": "site08"},
    {"node01": "site05", "node02": "site02"}
]
}
```

This is what i have so far

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="utf-8"> 

<!--Programming exercise 3-->

<html>
    <head>
        <title>network graph</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <svg></svg>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
            <script>

                //svg canvas
                    var svgCanvas = d3.select("svg")
                        .attr("width", 1000)
                        .attr("height", 650)
                        .attr("class", "svgCanvas");


                // load in data
                    d3.json("data.json", function(data){
                            console.log(data); 

                    // nodes
                        svgCanvas.selectAll("circle")
                            .data(data.nodes)
                            .enter()                    
                            .append("circle")
                                .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; } )
                                .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; } )
                                .attr("r", 10)
                                .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
                    // links
                        svgCanvas.selectAll("line")
                            .data(data.links)
                            .enter()
                            .append("line")
                                .attr("x1", function(d) { return } )
                                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.; } )
                                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.; } )
                                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.; } )
                                .style("stroke", "#aaa")                        
                    });

            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've been able to plot the nodes, but cant seem figure out how to plot the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your specific data structure, you just need to find the `x` and `y` position of the specific `links` value by the `id` of the `nodes`:

```
svgCanvas.selectAll("line")
    .data(data.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return data.nodes.find(function(e) {
        return e.id === d.node01
      }).x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return data.nodes.find(function(e) {
        return e.id === d.node01
      }).y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return data.nodes.find(function(e) {
        return e.id === d.node02
      }).x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return data.nodes.find(function(e) {
        return e.id === d.node02
      }).y;
    })
```

Here is the demo:

```html
<svg></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  //svg canvas
  var svgCanvas = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 650)
    .attr("class", "svgCanvas");


  var data = {
    "nodes": [{
        "id": "site09",
        "x": 317.5,
        "y": 282.5
      },
      {
        "id": "site01",
        "x": 112,
        "y": 47
      },
      {
        "id": "site02",
        "x": 42,
        "y": 147
      },
      {
        "id": "site05",
        "x": 212,
        "y": 95
      },
      {
        "id": "site08",
        "x": 10,
        "y": 200
      }
    ],
    "links": [{
        "node01": "site05",
        "node02": "site08"
      },
      {
        "node01": "site05",
        "node02": "site02"
      }
    ]
  };

  // nodes
  svgCanvas.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
  // links
  svgCanvas.selectAll("line")
    .data(data.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return data.nodes.find(function(e) {
        return e.id === d.node01
      }).x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return data.nodes.find(function(e) {
        return e.id === d.node01
      }).y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return data.nodes.find(function(e) {
        return e.id === d.node02
      }).x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return data.nodes.find(function(e) {
        return e.id === d.node02
      }).y;
    })
    .style("stroke", "#aaa")

</script>
```

As using `find` several times in the callbacks is computer intensive, a better approach is just populating the `links` array beforehand:

```
data.links.forEach(function(d) {
    var node1 = data.nodes.find(function(e) {
      return e.id === d.node01
    });
    var node2 = data.nodes.find(function(e) {
      return e.id === d.node02
    });
    d.x1 = node1.x;
    d.x2 = node2.x;
    d.y1 = node1.y;
    d.y2 = node2.y;
  });
```

And here is the demo:

```html
<svg></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  //svg canvas
  var svgCanvas = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 650)
    .attr("class", "svgCanvas");


  var data = {
    "nodes": [{
        "id": "site09",
        "x": 317.5,
        "y": 282.5
      },
      {
        "id": "site01",
        "x": 112,
        "y": 47
      },
      {
        "id": "site02",
        "x": 42,
        "y": 147
      },
      {
        "id": "site05",
        "x": 212,
        "y": 95
      },
      {
        "id": "site08",
        "x": 10,
        "y": 200
      }
    ],
    "links": [{
        "node01": "site05",
        "node02": "site08"
      },
      {
        "node01": "site05",
        "node02": "site02"
      }
    ]
  };

  data.links.forEach(function(d) {
    var node1 = data.nodes.find(function(e) {
      return e.id === d.node01
    });
    var node2 = data.nodes.find(function(e) {
      return e.id === d.node02
    });
    d.x1 = node1.x;
    d.x2 = node2.x;
    d.y1 = node1.y;
    d.y2 = node2.y;
  })

  // nodes
  svgCanvas.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
  // links
  svgCanvas.selectAll("line")
    .data(data.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.x1;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.y1;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.x2;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.y2;
    })
    .style("stroke", "#aaa")

</script>
```